# Looking for correct PHP socket error constants

Tags: php, sockets, constants

I have an odd problem that's likely due to my inexperience with socket programming.

I'm currently using the raw error code numbers I'm getting from `socket_last_error()` as I see I need to handle them. This is getting unwieldy.

I'd like to use predefined constants (either my own or builtin) to refer to the different types of socket errors/conditions I need to deal with.

The error tables I've found all use conflicting values.

At http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.constants.php (in a comment that lists the raw numbers), I see things like (excerpted):

```php
SOCKET_EINPROGRESS        10036
SOCKET_EALREADY           10037
SOCKET_ENETUNREACH        10051
```

The one comment at http://php.net/socket_last_error contains a list of what are apparently the "standard C defines" for socket errors (?):

```php
define('EINPROGRESS',   115);   /* Operation now in progress */ 
define('EALREADY',      114);   /* Operation already in progress */ 
define('ENETUNREACH',   101);   /* Network is unreachable */
```

The errno.h file on my own system (hiding in /usr/include/asm-generic/) seems to support this:

```c
#define EINPROGRESS     115     /* Operation now in progress */
#define EALREADY        114     /* Operation already in progress */
#define ENETUNREACH     101     /* Network is unreachable */
```

However those "standard definitions" seem to be subject to change depending on what OS you're on: [BSD4.4's errno.h](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4/newsrc/sys/errno.h.html) has things like

```c
#define EINPROGRESS 36      /* Operation now in progress */
#define EALREADY    37      /* Operation already in progress */
#define ENETUNREACH 51      /* Network is unreachable */
```

Now we know what the `socket_*` functions were inspired by though!

Finally, I find what seems to be a hint of an explanation hiding in [the VirtualBox source code](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/include/iprt/errno.h):

```c
#ifndef EALREADY
# if defined(RT_ERRNO_OS_BSD)
#  define EALREADY              (37)
# elif defined(RT_OS_LINUX)
#  define EALREADY              (114)
# else
#  define EALREADY              (149)
# endif
#endif
```

With all of this taken into account...

**`socket_last_error()` returns an `errno` of `101` when `Network is unreachable`**, as opposed to `51` or `10051`. So this function appears to be in apparent violation of the socket library's officially-supplied constants, and seems to be using Linux's error codes instead.

([EDIT after adding my answer]: The `101` stated above was obtained on Linux.)

So now that I seem to be in Undocumented and/or Seemingly Undefined Behavior land... what do I do now? I'm on Linux right now; do these values ever change?

Is there some way I can use the offical `SOCKET_*` constants? I certainly wouldn't mind doing so.

Comment: I found that under PHP 7.3.9 on Linux, `SOCKET_ENETUNREACH` is defined as 101.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've been researching this hard -- and also that the platform-specific stuff might be a nuisance. Let me suggest this code which will ostensibly fetch all defined constants grouped together as "sockets" constants:

```
$consts = get_defined_constants(TRUE);
$socket_constants = $consts["sockets"];
foreach($socket_constants as $key => $value){
    echo $key . '=' . $value . "\n";
}
```

From that, I was able to construct this function which you may find useful on any platform for finding the names of socket constants which might match

```
function get_socket_constant_names($to_check) {
    $consts = get_defined_constants(TRUE);
    $socket_constants = $consts["sockets"];
    $matches = array();
    foreach($socket_constants as $key => $value){
    if ($value ==  $to_check) {
        $matches[] = $key;
    }
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

This:

```
var_dump(get_socket_constant_names(101));
```

Yields this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(18) "SOCKET_ENETUNREACH"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did some digging.

## WARNING. PHP returns OS-specific socket error codes.

#### I do not know how to retrieve error codes compatible with the `socket_*` constants, so you have to detect the OS :'(

See proof after source code.

The following are heavily elided to aid focus.

From https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sockets/sockets.c:

```c
PHP_FUNCTION(socket_connect) {

    // will set errno
    retval = connect(php_sock->bsd_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    if (retval != 0) {
        // call macro defined in php_sockets.h with errno value
        PHP_SOCKET_ERROR(php_sock, "unable to connect", errno);
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    RETURN_TRUE;

}

PHP_FUNCTION(socket_last_error) {
    // check for argument
    if (arg1) {
        if ((php_sock = (php_socket *)zend_fetch_resource(Z_RES_P(arg1), le_socket_name, le_socket)) == NULL) {
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
        // return errno from passed socket resource
        RETVAL_LONG(php_sock->error);
    } else {
        // return errno from last globally set value
        RETVAL_LONG(SOCKETS_G(last_error));
    }
}
```

From https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sockets/php_sockets.h:

```c
#define PHP_SOCKET_ERROR(socket, msg, errn) \

    // store the value for this socket resource
    (socket)->error = _err; \

    // store the value globally
    SOCKETS_G(last_error) = _err
```

---

Proof:

```php
<?php

$s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_set_nonblock($s);

socket_connect($s, "google.com", "80");

var_dump(socket_last_error());
var_dump(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
```

**Observe the difference in `socket_last_error()`:**

```
linux$ php asdf.php
int(115)
string(25) "Operation now in progress"

freebsd$ php asdf.php
int(36)
string(25) "Operation now in progress"
```

**TL;DR: There's no defined list of constants inside PHP (that I can see how to use). You must supply your own OS-correct list of constants.**